# How can I compare WFEs to ensure a WSP was deployed succesfully?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, deployment, solution-package

I'm a sharepoint 2007 administrator.

We are running with two WFE and deployed a wsp package recently, we suspect that the deployment was not completely successful.

we would like to compare the WSPs on both the WFEs, is there a way to do it without dev-team help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the 12 hive and verify that the solution was deployed to both web front ends.  c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\templates\features

If the solution was installed with the option to install it in the gac, then you will want to validate that it is listed in the c:\windows\assembly view on both servers.

If it was not installed to the GAC, then you should be able to find it in the bin directory of the web application on both servers.

Answer (score 1):

Mikes solution is correct, but demands that you as administrator knows what the packages contains.

Did you already check in Central Administration under solution management that the deployment went well? Another option (that could be automated with a few lines of PowerShell code) is to use the command STSADM -o enumsolutions. This will return an xml string containing information about if the solution was deployed succesfully.

This should give you an indication if deployment on all WFE went well.